# Is the isometric path cover problem NP-complete?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete

Isometric path (like geodesic) is yet another name for shortest path. An isometric path cover is a set $S$ of isometric paths such that every vertex $v ∈ V$ belongs to at least one isometric path of $S$. The isometric path cover problem is to find a minimum cardinality isometric path cover of $G$. Is the isometric path cover problem  NP-complete for general graphs?

Comment: So you mean that the path cover can only contain a path $P$ if there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $P$ is a shortest path from $x$ to $y$?

Comment: According to Section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03868.pdf), this is an open question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That would make a good answer

Answer (score 3):

This question is mentioned in a recent (2017) paper, [Strong geodetic problem in networks:
computational complexity and solution for
Apollonian networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03868.pdf) by Paul Manuel, Sandi Klavžar, Antony Xavier,
Andrew Arokiaraj, and Elizabeth Thomas. On page 8, they state:

> To our knowledge, the complexity status of the isometric path problem is
>   not known.

Answer (score 0):

The isometric problem is important because of the following reasons:
The path cover problem is NP-complete.
The induced path-cover problem is NP-compete.
The status of the isometric path cover problem is unknown.